# demoProgram which can be of simple one

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-button, lwuit-dialog

I am creating a program in which i want to display dialog box(which shows yes/no command) when button clicked, after dialog box has been shown, when clicking yes button it moves to another form, can you help me to achieve this task? please let me know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the LWUIT repository [here...](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/source/browse/lwuit/) In this repository contains LWUIT sample applications. See the sample code. and do like this..

```
Dialog.show("Sample", "Put ur information", "Ok", "Cancel");
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Alert class ([link text](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/alerts20/index.html), the Form class, and the Display method to show stuff. That's pretty basic stuff and you'll find tons of examples / tutorials out there.

ps: Pure MIDP no LWUIT involved.